# vertical group with stack actor acting strange in libgdx

Tags: libgdx

Yet another libgdx group problem. I am trying to overlay Image actor with Slider. Slider's height is 55, underneath is bgImage, which should also have height 55. I am using this code. The goal is to achieve complete overlay, beacuse, slider on top is semi transparent. The problem is that the bgImage's height isn't the same as sliders(55), even though I set it with `setHeight()` method. I tracked the height of bgImage in render method. The result was interesting. Only the first time render was called, bgImage's height was 55,  on all subsequent render calls, bgImage's height was 140, therefore messing up my user interface. What could be the reason for change in height and what is the workaround? Thanks for help.

```
        Texture bgTexture=new Texture("underImage.png");
        bgImage= new Image(new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(bgTexture)));
        bgImage.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        bgImage.setWidth(hueSlider.getStyle().background.getMinWidth());
        bgImage.setPosition(0, 0);
        bgImage.setHeight(55);
        bgImage.setBounds(0,0,hueSlider.getWidth(),55);
        Texture overlayTexture=new Texture("gradientOverlay3.png");
        Slider.SliderStyle ss2=new Slider.SliderStyle();
        ss2.background= new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(overlayTexture));
        ss2.knob= new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(th));
        brightnessSlider=new Slider(1,100,1,false,ss2);

        stack=new Stack();
        stack.add(bgImage);
        stack.add(brightnessSlider);
        verticalGroup.addActor(hueSlider);
        verticalGroup.addActor(stack);

        table.add(verticalGroup).width(365).fillX();
        stage.addActor(table);
```

EDIT: brighntessSlider is on top and it's height is the same as the height of the image I use for background, namely 55.

This is implementation of render method. See the second sout statement. At that point the height is already 140. Veeeery strange.

```
public void render () {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        System.out.println("height" + bgImage.getHeight());

        camera.update();
        batch.begin();

        batch.end();

        stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
        stage.draw();
        System.out.println("height" + bgImage.getHeight());
    }
```